# Hide folders on NFS mounts

Tags: nfs, synology

I recently replaced Windows on my laptops with Linux and now I am using NFS instead of CIFS to access my Synology DS220+ NAS. A very annoying side effect is that I now have a directory called `@eaDir` in every directory on the NAS that contains image files, created by the Synology Photos Application to store thumbnails and metainformation about the images.

On CIFS mounts the directory is hidden, but on the NFS mounts it's visible. I know from my experience with NetApp storage systems (a completely different animal, I know) that it is generally possible to hide directories (`.snapshot` directory in this case) while it is still possible to enter them when you know the name.

I've been trying to find out if this is a feature of NFS itself which only has to be configured, but came up blank. Can anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: Can you change the names of those folders in NFS? For instance, rename `@eaDir` to `.eaDir`? That's the only way. Only files starting with `.` are considered hidden by different tools (`ls`, shells etc.). There's no way to change that.

Comment: Nope. That would have been too easy. I can't configure anything about it on the NAS side,  apart from uninstalling the photos app, which is not an option.

Comment: On NetApp shares the .snapshot dir, while technically a hidden file, does not even show up with 'ls -a', so there must be a mechanism.

Comment: That's a NetApp feature, it has nothing to do with the client side.